# Where to place model definition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on Thai language processing web application with very long object constructors(there is a `syllable` constructor with many `syllable` methods, a `word` constructor which turns a `string` into `syllable[]`, and a `sentence` constructor which turns a string into `word[]`). These are stuff that are not directly connected to the view but is used a lot in controllers.

I googled for *where to put object constructor in angularjs* and most web suggested that I should put it in a factory, but I don't quite understand, like, should I create a word factory and a sentence factory which contains array of word factory?

I'm very new to AngularJS and don't know where to put these stuff in. What are the possible ways to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: what have you tried? you need to rephrase your question so it's not a 'best practice' question for SO.

Comment: Put them in service and use them in controllers.

Comment: This might help - http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/.  Create individual models for 'syllable', 'word' and 'sentence' as they have their own methods and create a new service (like a 'manager' in this link) to combine behavior amongst all 3 models.